# Zend Framework IIS Redirection

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I have this rule for redirecting traffic to `/public`, but I get "redirect loop" error. Any suggestions?

```
<rule name="Redirect to /public" stopProcessing="true">
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^test.example\.com$" ignoreCase="false" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://test.example.com/{R:1}" />
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with iis redirect, but this might help -> http://forums.iis.net/t/1181128.aspx/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a loop because your rule is triggered when:

1. `url="(.*)"` => always true
2. `{HTTP_HOST}` matches `^test.example\.com$` => always true in your case

Your redirect rule is triggered by any url accessing your website.
It then redirects to your website with an url that will match again the rule...

If you want to redirect all the requests to `/public`, you can use the following rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect to /public" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^public/(.*)" negate="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="public/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

It checks if the url doesn't start with `public/`. If it is the case, it redirects to `public/UrlRequested`.

You can keep your `conditions` as well:

```
<rule name="Redirect to /public" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^public/(.*)" negate="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^test.example\.com$" ignoreCase="false" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="public/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```